# SG500 powers on, but won't boot, won't reset

Tags: cisco, hardware

I have a Cisco SG500-52 switch.

On boot the Fan light comes on green, and the System light starts blinking green.  No other lights show (no port lights at all).

I tried rebooting or resetting the switch using the small reset hole / button, but it doesn't respond at all.  Not after 10 seconds, nor 30 seconds, nor a minute.

Any ideas?  This switch did work at one time.

Comment: What shows on the console?

Comment: Console is interesting.  It starts with this message: `MAC address is not valid!  MAC address is not valid, you can't use multicast or broadcast address.  Enter MAC address and press ENTER( XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX ) :`  So it is asking me to enter in a MAC address?  I left it blank and pressed enter just to see what would happen.  Again it repeated `MAC address is not valid` and also `Error occurred - MAC address not changed`.  Then it asked for `Enter Hardware Revision (XX.XX.XX):`  Then it asked for `Enter Serial Number`. Seems like it is doing the initial setup that they do in the factory, maybe?

Comment: There is a `Serial Number` and a `MAC ID` on a barcode sticker on the back of the unit.  Maybe I should try entering these values?  However, I have no idea what to put for Hardware Revision.  There is a `PID VID` on the same sticker which is `SG500-52-K9 V01` but I'm not sure how to translate that into the `XX.XX.XX` format that the Console is requesting.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: No answer.  I ended up exchanging the device under warranty.

Comment: You can post that as an answer and accept it since any answer posted could not be tested by you. That will prevent the question from popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Quick Start manual](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbms/Sx500/quick_start/en/500_Series_QSG_En.pdf) suggests perhaps its performing a self-check or waiting to acquire an IP address.

> **Front Panel LEDs**
>
> Master—(Green) Lights steady when this switch is a stack master.
>
> Fan—(Green) Lights steady when the cooling fan is operational, blinks 
>   green if there is a failure.
>
> System LED—(Green) Lights steady when the switch is powered on, and 
>   **flashes when booting, performing self tests, or acquiring an IP address**. If the LED flashes Amber, the switch has detected a hardware failure.

Comment: For a normal boot process, all the port lights will flash on at some point.  This was not happening.  I ended up exchanging the device under warranty.